# Rails: Writing a function for a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, function

Hey I am quite new to Rails and I got a bit stuck So I have this div in rails that I am using over and over again to show icons. I want to write a function since there are about 20 images and 3 different states (inactive/active/completed)

My View

```
 <div class="position6">
   <%= link_to "course_6" do %>
   <%= image_tag '/icons/course_6_active.png', width: 150, height: 150, alt: ''%>
   <%end%>
</div>
```

Controller

```
def iconloader(number,state)
 <div class="position#{number}">
 <%= link_to "course_#{number}" do %>
 <%= image_tag '/icons/course_#{number}_#{state}.png', width: 150, height: 150, alt: ''%>
 <%end%>
end
```

I can't seem to figure out how to write a function for a div.(I know it should be really easy but I have been stuck for 2 days now) I am a bit lost. Also where do I put the function? In the controller or the view?

to rephrase my question a bit clearer: how would I use less code to achieve the same in my view using rails? It is a bit of a mess now.

Comment: where does `state` and `number` comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you want a function which will render simple HTML in your views, use a helper function. These are in `app/helpers`. Putting a method in `application_helper.rb` will be callable anywhere within your views.

As for rendering HTML in Ruby, you can use the following syntax:

**In application.rb:**

```
def iconloader(number, state)
  content_tag(:div, class: "position6") do
    link_to "course_6" do
      image_tag '/icons/course_6_active.png', width: 150, height: 150, alt: ''
    end
  end
end
```

Then, simply call the icon loader in your view:

```
<%= iconloader(number, state) %>
```

Also, I'd consider using a partial instead of a function to render HTML when possible. It's often easier to express HTML in HTML itself rather than Ruby, especially for more complex HTML.

Comment: Thanks, the helper function is what I was looking for!

Comment: At the end I did ened up using a partial instead of a function, Thanks !

Comment: Yup, I think a partial makes more sense in this example.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is a view helper

http://www.rails-dev.com/custom-view-helpers-in-rails-4

Comment: Thanks! This is what I am looking for